# Return rows where the full string in columnA exists as substring in ANY row of columnB

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
INSERT INTO names
    (`id`,`columnA`,`columnB`)
VALUES
    (1,'john','dog'),
    (2,'orange','john smith'),
    (3,'alex','alex'),
    (4,'match','man'),
    (5,'pony','orange')
```

For the dataset above, I'm trying to write a SQL query that returns rows `id`'s `1`,`2`, and `3`. These three `id`'s have values in columnA that exist as a substring in ANY row of columnB.

- `john` in row `1` (`columnA`) exists as a substring in `john smith` row `2` (`columnB`)
- `orange` in row `2` (`columnA`) exists as a substring in `orange` row `5` (`columnB`)
- `alex` in row `3` (`columnA`) exists as a substring in `alex` row `3` (`columnB`)

Comment: You could use the LIKE condition in your join criteria: `SELECT a.id FROM names a INNER JOIN names b ON b.columnB LIKE '%' || a.ColumnA || '%'`?

Comment: Thanks @JNevill! I haven't been able to get this to work yet. 

Any chance you could show me how to implement using LIKE condition here? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/081fa17 . I had to rename the two columns - for some reason SQLFiddle rejected the original names.

Comment: It will look a little different since that's mysql. Check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/081fa17/1

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I will try getting this to work in BigQuery 

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate a wildcard on a column name so that SQL searches for the string within a larger string.

SELECT *
FROM names
WHERE '%'+ columnA + '%' in (select '%' + columnB + '%'  from cte)

Answer (score 0):

Try below few options

```
select any_value(a).*
from your_table a, your_table b
group by to_json_string(a)
having logical_or(b.columnB like '%' || a.columnA || '%')
```

or/and

```
select * 
from your_table
where true
qualify string_agg(columnB, '|||') over() like '%' || columnA || '%'
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output (for both above options) is

[image]